# Python Login with Cookie and Preserve Login

Tags: python, authentication

I have an account at http://www.domaintools.com/research/reverse-ip/.  I've looked through their ajax search and attempted to perform a python lookup as follows:

```
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.domaintools.com/research/reverse-ip?    ajax=mReverseIP&call=getIPResults&args[0]=64.233.161.104+"&args[1]=20')
import base64
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'))[:-1]
authheader =  "Basic %s" % base64string
req.add_header("Authorization", authheader)
conn = urllib2.urlopen(req,timeout=5)
```

But I'm getting back, "Please Login".  So I'm assuming they don't support Basic Auth.

I then tried

```
req = urllib2.Request('https://secure.domaintools.com/log-in/?r=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domaintools.com%2Fresearch%2Freverse-ip%2F')
import base64
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'))[:-1]
authheader =  "Basic %s" % base64string
req.add_header("Authorization", authheader)
conn = urllib2.urlopen(req,timeout=5)
```

But I'm getting a cookies required error.

So my question is: If I do manage to add cookies to the second code sample, how can I use that request to make the lookup?  Can someone provide a code sample for this?

Thanks,

Sam

EDIT:  I searched some more and found the mechanize library.  Can someone suggest how to use it to make an Ajax request?

I've now gotten this far:

```
import mechanize
browser = mechanize.Browser() 
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.open('https://secure.domaintools.com/log-in/?r=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domaintools.com%2Fresearch%2Freverse-ip%2F')
browser.select_form(nr=0)

browser["username"] = 'username'
browser["password"] = 'pass'
browser.new_control("HIDDEN", "action", {})
control = browser.form.find_control("action")
control.readonly = False
browser["action"] = "login"
browser.method = "POST"
browser.action = "#"

response = browser.submit()
```

Now what?

Answer (score 0):

Hard way:

- Study how that page works, how forms is being submitted ,may be simple form submition with cookies or may be an AJAX call, then replicate that using some library

Easier Way:

- Browsers already do all this for you, you want this to be automated, use a headless browser like [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) and I think it will be sufficient for you. I have used it to automate many task which I used to do with twill/mechanize and was unsuccessful as pages are becoming complex with many AJAX calls and under the hood interactions. e.g. see [find pizaa using yelp](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/pizza.js) example to see how easy it can be

You can start phantomjs as a separate process e.g. using subprocess module and read stdout, if you need to avoid opening process each time, you can have  a separate process keeping long running phantomjs for such purpose.

Comment: what do you mean? I use phantomjs in my webapp to convert complex html to pdf, creating process in webapp is not such a big deal unless you have thousand users per hour

Comment: the problem still stands.  it's asking for login with phantomjs

Comment: @SamHammamy so first try to login

Comment: Please checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097856/using-phantomjs-to-ajax-login-and-then-submit-an-ajax-form-to-get-json-results